# How to get wildcard form ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I archive to get wildcard form name or ID?

I need to get form ID and both form are identical i only want Last digit in form ID for example in form1 I need 1 Please advice

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', '[id^=addformj]', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

var formid=//I need to get form id here 

alert('You have submited form ' + formid);


}
</script>
```

HTML is like this

```
<form id="form1">
<input id="value1">
</form>

<form id="form2">
<input id="value2">
</form>
```

I want to alert 1 if form ID 1 is submitted and 2 if Form ID 2 is submitted

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', '[id^=addformj]', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

var formid=//I need to get form id here 

alert('You have submited form ' + formid);


}
</script>
```

Comment: `parseInt(id.slice(4))` ( or the length of the form id without the number, so 8 if the id is addformj in the real code. ) Usually I want the opposite though, a longer name to properly identify which form it is. :)

Comment: Do you have control of the HTML? If so, get rid of the `id`, use the same class on both forms, and put the `1`, `2` etc in a `data` attribute which you can read when the `submit` event occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The form element can be accessed via the `this` keyword. Here's an example:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '[id^=form]', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log('The form: ', this);

  var formid = this.id;

  // Change substring start value based on length of the formid prefix. 
  alert('You have submited form ' + formid.substr(4));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1">
  <input id="value1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<form id="form2">
  <input id="value2">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead? Much more convenient.

```js
$('form').on('submit', handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form data-id="1">
  <input value="value1">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<form data-id="2">
  <input value="value2">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```